# Countdown not working in some cases

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm using countdown script for my home page. It loads at the first visit only. Then surf other web pages and come back to the home page, it's not loading.

I'm using meteor and react.

```
componentDidMount () {
$(window).load(() => {
 $('#clock').countdown('2016/9/9', function (event) {
     var $this = $(this).html(event.strftime(''
       + '<span>%m</span> months '
       + '<span>%w</span> weeks '
       + '<span>%d</span> days '
       + '<span>%H</span> hr '
       + '<span>%M</span> min '
       + '<span>%S</span> sec'));
  });
}); }
```

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Browser caching is the problem

Comment: Nop. Checked it with different browsers.

Comment: How did you check and come to the conclusion that caching is not the problem?

Comment: Cleared bower cache, offline website data etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's definitely not a good idea to be mixing React and jQuery DOM manipulation. In fact, it doesn't make any sense to call `$(window).load` inside of `componentDidMount` because `componentDidMount` already ensures the React component is loaded into the DOM.

[Here](http://w33ble.github.io/understanding-react/demos/countdown.html) is an example of a simple countdown timer using a purely "Reactive" approach. I also copied the source code in case the link becomes invalid:

```
var CountdownTimer = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      secondsRemaining: 0
    };
  },
  tick: function() {
    this.setState({secondsRemaining: this.state.secondsRemaining - 1});
    if (this.state.secondsRemaining <= 0) {
      clearInterval(this.interval);
    }
  },
  componentDidMount: function() {
    this.setState({ secondsRemaining: this.props.secondsRemaining });
    this.interval = setInterval(this.tick, 1000);
  },
  componentWillUnmount: function() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>Seconds Remaining: {this.state.secondsRemaining}</div>
    );
  }
});

React.renderComponent(<CountdownTimer secondsRemaining="10" />, document.querySelector('#output'));
```

The timer is dictated by the component's state, which is decremented through the `tick` function. The `tick` function itself is polled every `x` seconds using `setInterval`.

I know your use case is more complicated since it requires counting down months, weeks, days, etc from a specific calendar date. You could either code that yourself (wouldn't be too hard) or find an appropriate `npm` library to do that for you.